# MySql Daily Report

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join

I am trying to get some help fixing my complex query. I am explaining below my situation, thanks.

I have the following two tables:

```
ACTIVITY TABLE:

ID   USER_ID      CARD_ID    CLOCK
1      123        04675545   4/3/2013 1:07:06 PM
2      123        04675545   4/3/2013 2:08:06 PM
3      124        04675550   4/3/2013 2:07:06 PM
4      124        04675550   4/3/2013 4:07:06 PM
5      124        04675550   4/4/2013 10:07:06 AM
6      124        04675550   4/4/2013 2:00:00 PM
7      124        04675550   4/5/2013 4:07:06 PM
8      124        04675550   4/7/2013 8:00:00 AM
9      124        04675550   4/7/2013 5:00:00 PM

PRICE TABLE:

ID    FROMTIME    TOTIME       PRICEPERHOUR
1     08:00:00    19:59:59     50.00
2     20:00:00    07:59:59     75.00
```

And the following query:

```
select a.user_id, date(a.clock),  ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.clock, b.clock))/3600)*c.PRICEPERHOUR as total from 
(Select if((@rn:=@rn+1)%2=0,@rn,@rn-1) As rId, act.* from act
join (select @rn:=-1)a
order by user_Id, clock) a 
inner join 
(Select if((@rn1:=@rn1+1)%2=0,@rn1,@rn1-1) As rId, act.* from act
join
(select @rn1:=-1)b
order by user_Id, clock) b
ON a.rid=b.rid AND a.id <> b.id 
inner join 
price c
on 
TIME_TO_SEC(a.clock) between TIME_TO_SEC(c.FROMTIME) 
AND 
TIME_TO_SEC(c.TOTIME)
group by a.user_id, date(a.clock)
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
USER_ID    DATE(A.CLOCK)                    TOTAL  
123        April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000     50.8333
124        April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000     100
124        April, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000     194.0833
124        April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000     1,994.0833
124        April, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000     1,994.0833
```

However, I am trying to get this result instead:

```
USER_ID    DATE(A.CLOCK)                    TOTAL  
123        April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000     50.8333
124        April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000     100
124        April, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000     194.0833
124        April, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000     50
124        April, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000     450
```

This is part of a clock system. Each time the user check-in, one entry gets recorded on the database. A correct user behavior will be that it has always a pair record recorded. For example user_id 123 clocks at 1:07:06pm and clocks again at 2:08:06pm. However, in some situations, the user may do it just once (unpaired record on the database) and therefore it should only be charged that particular hour from the record. As an example, user 124 on day 4/5/2013.

I am trying all weekend to get this query working :(. Once I get the correct result, I will add a condition to get only one user_id also, (e.g. where user_id=124).

Comment: @Meherzad, any idea on the best approach for the above? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think even if you manage to do this there are are some potential design pitfalls:

Can people clock in for more than 1 period per day? If so then 2 records for example
10am and 2pm could total 2hours or 4hours.

What happens if people clock in at 11pm and again at 2am?

From a quick glance I don't think your sql takes into account time periods that span across the 2 different pay rates? You should definitely include this scenario in your test data.

If I was going to implement this I would probably move the logic into code, and simplify the price table by only having one time column like:

```
TIME, PRICE
 00:00,  75.00
 08:00,  50.00
 20:00,  75.00
```

Also if a user only has one card you may not need to have card_id and user_id in the activity table.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks a lot for stepping in and my apologize for the late response. I did not know that this post was answered. Taking into account your comments, I am modifying the design to make it better. I will post here what I have done as soon as I am finished.